# $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symetric and positive definite.
Show that $\forall i\neq j; i,j=1,2,...,n; $   $a^2_{ij}<a_{ii}a_{jj}$

I tried to do this by contradiction and show that one of the leading principal minors isn't positive but this didn't lead me anywhere and I'm not sure it is a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Notice that $(e_i+\lambda e_j)^tA(e_i+\lambda e_j)=\lambda ^2a_{jj}+2\lambda a_{ij}+a_{ii}>0$, for every $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore $(2a_{ij})^2-4a_{jj}a_{ii}<0$.

Comment: To be formal, should I begin with: consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\lambda):=(e_i+\lambda e_j)^tA(e_i+\lambda e_j)$ ?

Comment: @TheMeff You can begin with the definition of $f(\lambda)$, but you must say that since $f(\lambda)$ is a quadratic polynomial and always positive, for every $\lambda$,  then its discriminant $(2a_{ij})^2-4a_{jj}a_{ii}$ is negative.